# Install Theme Kit with Chocolatey (theme version theme : The term 'theme' is not recognized )

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, chocolatey

when I installed Theme Kit with Chocolatey , it installed successfully - themekit - themekit v1.1.1 already installed.

[image: img]

but when I check it  by  theme version , it says theme : The term 'theme' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Your install command did *not* install successfully. It believes it's already installed because it was likely installed at one point, and it may have been removed without Chocolatey, but that is no guarantee. If it is installed, it's possible the installation is damaged/corrupt. You can try one of these to install the package:

1. Make sure you installed from an administrative command prompt. Many packages don't work when installing to the user scope. Unless you have UAC disabled VSCode doesn't open elevated (without asking it to).

   Your first screenshot cuts off the top of another warning, which is the same color as the warning that you are not elevated. This could be the issue. If this isn't the problem, read on (and please provide the TEXT output in your question, not a screenshot, please).
2. ```
   choco install themekit --force
   ```

   This will force the package to re-install without checking that it already exists.
3. ```
   choco uninstall themekit; choco install themekit
   ```

   Uninstall and reinstall the package. Some software may need a reboot, but I don't know about `themekit`.
4. ```
   Move-Item -Recurse $env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\themekit ~\Desktop
   choco install -y themekit
   ```

   Be careful with this one. The `lib` folder is where the package files are downloaded to during installation for each package (the folder is named after the package-id), and when packages don't use EXE, MSI, etc. to install the software, this can also be where the program files are stored. Move or delete the `themekit` folder in `lib` to somewhere outside of `$env:ChocolateyInstall`. Don't mess anything else up in this folder though; this is how Chocolatey keeps track of what packages are installed on your system.

   Once you move the package folder then just install the package again.

---

If none of this works, you will have to contact the [package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/themekit) maintainer and report this as an issue, and install manually in the meantime.